# How to query created_at field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5

When trying to find all records where the `created_at` time is larger than a certain value, it does not seem to work.

For example I have tried this:

```
return Foo::where('created_at', '>', '1457408361')->get();
```

But it keeps returning all the records!

Comment: @JilsonThomas Timestamp.

Comment: Use date instead of Timestamp date()

Answer (score 5):

Use the `whereDate()` query method:

```php
$date = Carbon::yesterday(); // Create date however you want

Foo::whereDate('created_at', '>', $date);
```

If you do these types of queries a lot, I’d consider wrapping it into a query scope:

```php
use DateTimeInterface;

class Foo extends Model
{
    public function scopeCreatedAfter(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('created_at', '>', $date);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
Foo::createdAfter($date)->get();
```

Comment: What is `whereDate` excatly

Comment: Lol. But what's the difference between `where` and `whereDate`

Comment: A method for adding `WHERE` clauses that operate on date columns.

Comment: I think I got it. `whereDate` is used with an actual instance of a Carbon Object

Comment: Not necessarily. It’s just that Carbon instances’ `__toString()` method formats dates as a string can use for querying dates (i.e. `2016-03-08 14:50:00`).

Comment: so what exactly is the difference between `->where('created_at', '>', $timeFrom)` and `->whereDate('created_at', '>', $timeFrom)` as they both seem to work?

Answer (score 4):

You can always use Carbon to convert the UNIX timestamp:

```php
Foo::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1457408361))->get();
```

So you can convert your integer to Carbon instance and compare it as above.

You can read about Carbon here: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: @YahyaUddin It's not

Comment: Why are you using `now()` in your example? Why anyone could use query where you search for a date which is '>=' than `now`? I guess your example `'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()` can't return anything.

Comment: You can create any timestamp from any integer using carbon. I'm using mobile now so I wouldn't be able to give you an example. But please check the document link provided above and you'll be good to go.